# Issues with excel template/blank workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm having very weird issues with all excel 2016 files on Windows 10 (new and existing).

Anytime I enter text the cell style is being changed. This also applies to deleting or changing the cell. If I change cell style to "normal" everything is fine, but as soon as I enter new text the issue occurs again.

Here's an example of what I mean - https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqMur.jpg

I have tried to reinstall but I'm still getting the same issue. I think it has to do with Excel using a template, but I can't find where it's pulling it from.

Also, I have no Conditional Formatting Rules or Macros running.

The following folders do not contain any file - `C:\Users\alanredd\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART`, `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\XLSTART`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Couple questions..1) have all the Office updates been installed? 2) Is this computer clean of all viruses and malware? Also, you need to ask a specific question. Not doing so leaves it open to misunderstanding what you are asking.

Comment: Hi the computer is clean no malware, all updates are installed. Win 10 latest with Office 2016. I'm not sure what is causing this issue so I guess what question is how do I disable what ever is running?

Comment: I would suggest you open Excel in [safe mode](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Open-Office-apps-in-safe-mode-on-a-Windows-PC-dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7ac72) to see if the issue remains. If not, then start looking at disabling Add-ins to see which ones may be causing the issue.

Comment: It happens in safe mode as well. I downloaded random templates from the internet and it occurs for them as well. It's like some setting has been triggered but I have no idea what it is.

Comment: When you tried to reinstall, did you completely remove (uninstall) before you did that? If not, I would suggest complete uninstall, reboot the computer and attempt a reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone has a similar issue it was a bug with Excel - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4011165/september-12-2017-update-for-excel-2016-kb4011165